# How to CONCAT custom string into column names of joined table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have these two tables `company.tbl`:

```
+------------+---------------+--------------+
| COMPANY_ID | COMPANY_NAME  | COMPANY_CITY |
+------------+---------------+--------------+
```

and `foods.tbl`

```
+---------+--------------+-----------+------------+
| ITEM_ID | ITEM_NAME    | ITEM_UNIT | COMPANY_ID |
+---------+--------------+-----------+------------+
```

I need to add `_foo`, only to the end of all joined columns from `foods.tbl`

```
+------------+---------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+
| COMPANY_ID | COMPANY_NAME  | COMPANY_CITY | ITEM_ID_foo | ITEM_NAME_foo| ITEM_UNIT_foo | COMPANY_ID_foo|
+------------+---------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+
```

How can I achieve this?

```
SELECT *
FROM company
LEFT JOIN foods ON company.company_id = foods.company_id;
```

Comment: You really have tables named `tbl` in two different schemas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Use Alias

```
SELECT 
            company.COMPANY_ID as COMPANY_ID
           ,company.COMPANY_NAME as COMPANY_NAME
           ,company.COMPANY_CITY as COMPANY_CITY
           ,foods.ITEM_ID       as ITEM_ID_foo
           ,foods.ITEM_NAME     as ITEM_NAME_foo
           ,foods.ITEM_UNIT     as ITEM_UNIT_foo
           ,foods.COMPANY_ID    as COMPANY_ID_foo

FROM   company
LEFT JOIN foods
ON company.company_id = foods.company_id;
```

You can Use Default Value by Dynamic

```
declare   @defaultValue varchar(max)='_foo'

declare @sql varchar(max)='SELECT 
            company.COMPANY_ID as COMPANY_ID
           ,company.COMPANY_NAME as COMPANY_NAME
           ,company.COMPANY_CITY as COMPANY_CITY
           ,foods.ITEM_ID       as ITEM_ID_foo
           ,foods.ITEM_NAME     as ITEM_NAME'+@defaultValue+
           ',foods.ITEM_UNIT     as ITEM_UNIT'+@defaultValue+
           ',foods.COMPANY_ID    as COMPANY_ID'+@defaultValue+

' FROM   company
LEFT JOIN foods
ON company.company_id = foods.company_id;'

exec(@sql)
```

You can Use Default Value and column food by Dynamic
,also You can Choose Specific columns of food table

```
declare   @defaultValue varchar(max)='_foo'
declare   @columnfoods varchar(max)='_foo'

select @columnfoods=STRING_AGG( '
           foods.' +COLUMN_NAME +' as ' +COLUMN_NAME +@defaultValue,',')
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where TABLE_NAME='foods' and TABLE_SCHEMA= 'dbo'
--and COLLATION_NAME in ('')
declare @sql varchar(max)='SELECT 
            company.COMPANY_ID as COMPANY_ID,
            company.COMPANY_NAME as COMPANY_NAME,
            company.COMPANY_CITY as COMPANY_CITY ,
           ' +@columnfoods+
'
FROM   company
LEFT JOIN foods
ON company.company_id = foods.company_id;'

exec(@sql)
```

Comment: Thanks for reply Abolfazl, but cant we make this a little bit more dynamic?

Comment: I edited my code and use dynamic defaultValue  and Column table Food

Comment: @Behseini if you want a dynamic solution please ensure you say that in your question.